# Folder Permisson for cache folders Centos7 and nginx 1.10

Tags: nginx, permissions, centos7, magento

I have a server on which I install Centos 7.2 and nginx 1.10.
I would like zo host Magento

What I have done:

- `root` user is disabled
- `newuser` is admin user for doing stuffs with sudo
- I have a new nginx server block enabled
- set domain new block root folder to `/var/www/example.com/html`
- set folder permission to

  - `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/example.com/html (logged in as 'newuser')`
  - `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`

now the Magento root settings

```
set permissions to->
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
chmod +x mage
```

My problem is that the cache and session folder is empty

Fist question why?

NOTE: I don't know where but somewhere the caches are stored because to see changes on Magento Frontend I have to clear the Cache after doing that in the Admin panel I could see changes.

So the second question is it a permission problem?

Should I give the Magento root  and `/var/www/example.com/html` permission to an normal user?

Answer (score 0):

1. Why might the cache and sessions directories be empty? Because cache and sessions can live in memcache, redis or even mysql if you tell magento that’s where to put them!  Check your magento `local.xml`, and you will see sections for both `session` and `cache`.  It may be that you are, for example, using redis for cache and database for sessions.
2. See (1), without more information, we don’t know if it is a permissions problem.  But if it is, you can make the `var` folder and all sub folders 0777 (or 0775 if you have a group that the nginx / php-fpm user is also a part of) as long as you have already protected your `var` folder in nginx.